# Capturing the Lead deletion log using dynamic apex

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql, dynamic

I am trying to create an entry in the deletion_log__c object before the lead record gets deleted. I would like to capture all the lead field names along with values in the deletion_log__c object with the respective field values . I would like my code to be dynamic(I mean in future if i create any new fields , the same field values also should get captured with out modifying the existing code).

I am using the below code for the same.

```
trigger leadTrg on Lead (before delete) {

public Map <String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();

 list<Deletion_Log__c> leadDeletionLogList = new list<Deletion_Log__c>();
 Schema.SObjectType leadSchema = schemaMap.get('Lead');
 Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = leadSchema.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
for (lead l: trigger.old){

    Deletion_Log__c leadDeletionLog = new Deletion_Log__c ();


    string logRecord ;

    for (String fieldName: fieldMap.keySet())
    { 
        system.debug('fieldName&&&'+fieldName);
        String fieldLabel = fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getLabel();


        Schema.DisplayType fielddataType = fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getType();

        s1 = s1+fieldName+'='+l.fieldName;

     }

     leadDeletionLog.data__c =  s1 ;
     leadDeletionLogList.add(leadDeletionLog);

  }
  insert leadDeletionLogList;
}
```

However, I am not able to save the code , I am getting the error message

> "Invalid field fieldName for SObject Lead "

The statement " s1 = s1+fieldName+'='+l.fieldName;" is causing the error, I am clueless about the reason, has anyone ever encountered this error?

Comment: I notice that l.fieldName is belong to Lead in for(Lead l:trigger.old) which is not exist, that's why it throw error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        s1 = s1+fieldName+'='+l.fieldName;
```

You need to use the SObject#get method to get a field value dynamically:

```
        s1 = s1+fieldName+'='+String.valueOf(l.get(fieldName));
```